# React and Redux: Console not displaying error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am trying to print the error in my console but my console is not displaying anything. Console.log(err) is in the catch block right before dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'LOGIN_FAIL'));

//Login user

```
export const login = ({email, password, history}) => dispatch =>{
  
  const config = {
    headers:{
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };


  const body = JSON.stringify({email, password});

  axios.post('/api/user/login/', body, config)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    })
    history.push('/userfeed')
  })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err)
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'LOGIN_FAIL'));
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Hey my friend , are you sure that the response of the api that call axios , its return a status code different than 200, if the api response 200 will enter on .then( for example it the request returns 500 status it will enter on .catch, just verify this

Comment: I have the error status at 400. I saw it on my redux DevTool

Comment: It just doesnt display anything. Even if I manually enter something in the console.log() I still do not see it in my console. I keep getting an error on my browser so thats why I want to see what exactly is the error in my console.

Comment: i dont know but this look strange to me ,  const body = JSON.stringify({email, password}), dont need to JSON.stringify , just pass normal js object like const body = {email,password}, try this solution and let me know : )

Comment: Just tried it and it did not work.

Comment: try this, comment dispatchs and make only the request from axios maybe the problem its on dispatcher, try to comment all dispatchers  and add console.log inside then and catch, i will be nice to view request results and status made from axios on dev console.

Comment: I didnt work. I commented out all dispatches

Comment: Sorry I was looking at my command panel console which is why I was not seeing. I looked into my browser console and I saw the error. It said undefined